# Installing the deb package using apt install

Tags: linux, deb

If the previous version of the deb package is not installed, then the installation via `apt install` is correct. But if the previous version of the deb package is installed on the system, an error occurs

```
chmod: cannot access '/opt/mplc4_installer/install.sh': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mplc4-oni-plc-w (--configure):
 installed mplc4-oni-plc-w package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mplc4-oni-plc-w
```

My postinst script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeu
chmod u+x opt/mplc4_installer/install.sh
cd opt/mplc4_installer/
./install.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
exit $?
```

Comment: which package? which Linux distro?

Comment: Package was created by me, Debian 11.7

Comment: Then the big is most probably in your package, exactly at the apt output suggests!

Comment: Most likely the problem is in my package, but why is the package installed during a clean installation, and when calling again, for example apt install, an error occurs

Comment: so, but then how should we help you debug this without even seeing the failing post-installation script?